# How to use mathjax from command line?

Tags: javascript, math, mathjax

I was hoping to use Mathjax to render some mathjax snippets into svg files.

At this point I believe that a command in the form

```
<javascript interpter> <Mathjax jax file> 'mathjax snippet here'
```

should work, I'm not sure what `jax` file I'm supposed to pick and how to set the output mode that I want, or how to configure mathjax in general when calling it from the command line.

I need this because I have to render this math expressions offline without a browser.

Answer (score 5):

See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mathjax-users/nQXVaFi4IKQ/AwZ-UrRhiDAJ) on the MathJax forum for some code that does this using Phantom.js (there are some subtleties to be considered, so look at the code carefully if you need to modify it).  Several others have taken this further.  The svgtex project listed in that conversation apparently has been discontinued in favor of the [Mathoid](https://github.com/gwicke/mathoid) project that underlies Wikimedia's latest math support code.

EDIT: there is now the [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/) project that uses node.js to run MathJax via the command line  or via your own node.js code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use nodejs with some wrappers for MathJax - https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=Mathjax

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am not expert in mathjax. but i read have read a article on it. I am passing some links to you. One of which is a documentation of it. Hope it helps you.
[documentation pdf.](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/mathjax/v2.0-latest/mathjax.pdf) and [second one](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html)